# transforming image using OpenCV dft and idft, looks completely white when saved

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I wrote the following code to convert several images. Until img_back, the image was converted correctly, but when this image is saved, only the white image is saved.
how to solve? thank you.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

n=100
for number in range(0,n+1):
    filename_o = 'image/{1:06d}.png'.format(number)
    original_img = cv2.imread(filename_o,0)
    print(original_img)

    #convert img->magnitude inverse ft
    dft = cv2.dft(np.float32(original_img),flags = cv2.DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT)
    dft_shift = np.fft.fftshift(dft)
    rows, cols = original_img.shape
    crow,ccol = int(rows/2), int(cols/2)

    mask = np.zeros((rows,cols,2),np.uint8)
    mask[crow-30:crow+30, ccol-30:ccol+30] = 1

    fshift = dft_shift*mask
    f_ishift = np.fft.ifftshift(fshift)
    img_back = cv2.idft(f_ishift)
    img_back = cv2.magnitude(img_back[:,:,0],img_back[:,:,1])

    print(type(img_back))
    #save as ...
    #cv2.cvtColor(np.uint8(img_back), cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)

    cv2.imwrite('image_mag/{1:06d}.png'.format(number), img_back)



print("finish")
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I don’t know exactly , but you can try normalising the image before saving it. According to me, probably the image pixel values are greater than 255 mostly, so, OpenCV might be clipping greater values to 255 thus giving white image. You can give it a try.

Comment: @SangHyunPark Can you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71192089/edit) your question to include a sample of the input images `image/{1:06d}.png` to make a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data in `img_back` at a very high scale. I suggest normalizing the data before writing it to an image:

```py
normalized = img_back / img_back.max() * 255.0
cv2.imwrite('image_mag/{0:06d}.png'.format(number), normalized)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `DFT_SCALE` flag in either the `dft()` call or the `idft()` call.

Sections from the documentation:

- [`idft`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gaa708aa2d2e57a508f968eb0f69aa5ff1)
- [`dft`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gadd6cf9baf2b8b704a11b5f04aaf4f39d)

When you encounter issues, always review the documentation of the things you use.